# Laravel Php take random results from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I cannot find the way to display random results from a collection in laravel mysql. My query:

```
public function getTabletsProducts()
{
    return DB::table('products')
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->where('categoryName', 'All Tablets')
        ->where('sellingPrice', '<', 1000)
        ->take(6)
        ->orderByRaw("RAND()")
        ->get();
}
```

They weird thing is that I believed that using RAND would perform the job, but my results display same values using or not (rand).

any help appreciated.

Comment: See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: My answer should work nicely for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `take(6)->inRandomOreder()->get()`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that's because you take 6 items at first and then order them randomly. So you always get the same or the near result. If I were you I would try this:

```
public function getTabletsProducts()
{
return DB::table('products')
    ->where('categoryName', 'All Tablets')
    ->where('sellingPrice', '<', 1000)
    ->orderByRaw("RAND()")
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->take(6)
    ->get();
 }
```

Comment: and bring the order by created at to the end of the script before take